# How to build RTSP Server from RTP Stream?

Tags: webrtc, video-streaming, rtsp, live-streaming, rtp

**Context**

I have a DVR that has a camera and it uses a SIM card to communicate with the external world. If the DVR receives an instruction over TCP to perform live streaming, the DVR starts sending RTP packets through TCP to a server.

**Problem**

What can I use to build an RTSP Server from the RTP stream that I'm receiving? I already tested out this repository: https://github.com/ngraziano/SharpRTSP but it is highly coupled to the examples they have. The idea is to live stream the video that I'm receiving through RTP packets.

Even if you think RTSP is not the best option and I could achieve better results with WebRTC let me know. I'm new to this subject, I'm trying to solve this but something seems to be missing.

Note: I saw some existing questions about this but they seem outdated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [GStreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) is a good option in your case.

You can receive the RTP source from your camera using the [rtpsrc](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtpmanagerbad/rtpsrc.html?gi-language=c) element, and then pipe it through to an [rtspclientsink](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtspclientsink/plugin-index.html?gi-language=c) element.

If you need to do any other processing or transcoding, GStreamer certainly has plugins that will suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you @Inogueir Will have a look at this